# Can't set value into selected tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have following application [image]

all the data showen by following code.

```
<table id="bankmail" class="table table-bordred table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <th> Title </th>
                    <th> Year </th>
                    <th> Producer </th>
                    <th> &nbps; </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableBody">
                    <% table.forEach(function(row) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dialog">
                            <%= row.title %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dialog">

                            <%= row.year %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="dialog">
                            <%= row.producer  %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="getData(<%= row.year %>)" data-target="#modalCart">+</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

When you click button +
 tried to set to new value of to year12 this dosn't shown up what might be problem ?

```
function getData(da){
            console.log(da); //This works fine in console 
            $("#year12").val(da).change(); // Not Working dosn't react why
        }
```

Can't set new value of to year12 ???
What might be problem ??
I tried to show up in following places inside of modal

```
        <!--Body-->
        <div class="modal-body">

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>year</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td id="year12">

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

**How to set a new value of year12 td in jquery ??**

Comment: Just use `$("#year12").val(da);` instead of `$("#year12").val(da).change();`

Comment: I tried not working

Comment: Probably jQuery can't find it because it is generated dynamically. Try `document.getElementById("year12").val(da);`

Comment: tried document.getElementById("year12").value = da; didn't work

Comment: ok. let's try `$("#year12").attr("value",da);`. Also, check for javascript errors in the console.

Comment: tried this one also in console there is no errors

Comment: There is something I don't understand. Do you want to set the value of the year12(like `<td id="year12" value="value_here")></td>`)? Or, you want to change the text inside the <td></td>. Cause, if you want the latter, you have to use `$("#year12").html(da);`

Comment: thank you sir I just wanted to change of text td and last one worked for me

Comment: I am going to write an answer below, so anyone can see it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the text inside of the

```
<td id="year12">text in here</td>
```

you have to use `$("#year12").html(da);`